# Pandas 'isin' with output keeping order of input list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

When I have a dataframe

```
df = DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df

   A  B
0  5  1
1  6  2
2  3  3
3  4  5
```

I can use

```
df[df['A'].isin([3, 6])]
```

in order to select rows having the passed values.

Is there also a way to keep the order of the input list?

So that my output is not:

```
   A  B
1  6  2
2  3  3
```

but

```
   A  B
1  3  3
2  6  2
```

Comment: Doing `df[...]` with boolean indexing keeps the order of the DataFrame, regardless of whether the `...` part involves `isin` or not.  You would have to reorder your DataFrame separately, before or after applying `isin`.

Comment: ok, isn't there a way to reorder the output by using the input list as rule?

Comment: No, because `isin` is only for checking whether each item at a time "is in" the list at all, not *where* it is in the list.  It doesn't pay attention to the list's order.  Like I said, you would need to do the ordering in a separate step.

Answer (score 7):

This question is a bit old, but I stumbled into having to do this. This is how I resolved the problem. I believe it's quite a generic and simple solution that hasn't been proposed yet here, and that actually doesn't use the `isin()` method:

```
df.set_index('A').loc[[3,6]].reset_index()
```

With the example provided:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
>>> df.set_index('A').loc[[3,6]].reset_index()
   A  B
0  3  3
1  6  2
```

Of course, this has the disadvantage that it loses the original index. To preserve the index you could also:

```
>>> df.reset_index().set_index('A').loc[[3,6]].reset_index().set_index('index')
       A  B
index      
2      3  3
1      6  2
```

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for! Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit long, but it works. isin(), then sort_values() based on the list.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5]})
mylist = [3,6]
ndf =  df[df['A'].isin(mylist)]
ndf['sort_cat'] = pandas.Categorical(ndf['A'], categories=mylist, ordered=True)
ndf.sort_values('sort_cat', inplace=True)
ndf.reset_index(inplace=True)
print ndf
   A  B sort_cat
2  3  3        3
1  6  2        6
```

(I based this answer on [sort pandas dataframe based on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707171/sort-pandas-dataframe-based-on-list))

Answer (score 4):

Another option which filters and sorts in one shot

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
reduce(pd.DataFrame.append, map(lambda i: df[df.A == i], [3, 6]))
```

Comment: This works, but takes a long time (7-10 seconds) on a list with 7000-ish indices

Answer (score 3):

You can make the input list a dataframe and use the merge function. I've found this particularly useful for large input lists where order matters.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
input = pd.DataFrame({'input': [3, 6]})
output = input.merge(df, left_on='input', right_on='A').loc[:, ['A', 'B']]
print(output)

   A  B
0  3  3
1  6  2
```

There are 2 caveats. First, you have to specify which column of df you are searching for the match using the 'right_on' input to the merge function. Secondly, the indices of the resulting output dataframe are re-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best solution I found:

```
 df.iloc[pd.Index(df.A).get_indexer([3,6])]
```

Result:

```
>>> df.iloc[pd.Index(df.A).get_indexer([3,6])]
   A  B
2  3  3
1  6  2
```

Credit: [@cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658723/how-to-maintain-order-when-selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

`isin` is a set operation, and pandas aligns the input, so order of the input set is normally in the same order as the reference frame

You could if you REALLY want to do this:

```
In [15]: df.take(df['A'][df['A'].isin([3,6])].order().index)
Out[15]: 
   A  B
2  3  3
1  6  2

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I ended up using 
[x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(this,list(df.B[df.A.isin([3,6])])))]
giving me the wanted result.
Unfortunately I could not achieve the same by your solution.

Comment: Nikita's solution fails for me with  NameError: name 'this' is not defined
I found that Jeff's solution works for the example df, but not for a longer df.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same but in my problem this solution provides me the data frame in the same order as the list in the "isin" function which is what I wanted. Take a look here

[How to maintain order when selecting rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658723/how-to-maintain-order-when-selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/56659970)

Perhaps it could help you.