# How to maintain order when selecting rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select rows in a particular order given in a list. For example

This dataframe

```
a=[['car',1],['bike',3],['jewel',2],['tv',5],['phone',6]]

df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['items','quantity'])

>>> df
   items  quantity
0    car         1
1   bike         3
2  jewel         2
3     tv         5
4  phone         6
```

I want to get the rows with this order `['tv','car','phone']`, that is, first row tv and then car and then phone. I tried this method but it doesn't maintain order

```
arr=['tv','car','phone']

df.loc[df['items'].isin(arr)]

   items  quantity
0    car         1
3     tv         5
4  phone         6
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a non-intrusive solution using [`Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) that doesn't involve setting the index:

```
df.iloc[pd.Index(df['items']).get_indexer(['tv','car','phone'])]

   items  quantity
3     tv         5
0    car         1
4  phone         6
```

Note that if this is going to become a frequent thing (by thing, I mean "indexing" with a list on a column), you're better off turning that column into an index. Bonus points if you sort it.

```
df2 = df.set_index('items')
df2.loc[['tv','car','phone']]  

       quantity
items          
tv            5
car           1
phone         6
```

Answer (score 7):

IIUC `Categorical`

```
df=df.loc[df['items'].isin(arr)]
df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df['items'],categories=arr,ordered=True).argsort()]
Out[157]: 
   items  quantity
3     tv         5
0    car         1
4  phone         6
```

Or `reindex` :Notice only different is this will not save the pervious index and if the original index do matter , you should using `Categorical` (Mentioned by Andy L, if you have duplicate in items ,`reindex` will ***failed*** )

```
df.set_index('items').reindex(arr).reset_index()
Out[160]: 
   items  quantity
0     tv         5
1    car         1
2  phone         6
```

Or loop via the `arr`

```
pd.concat([df[df['items']==x] for x in arr])
Out[171]: 
   items  quantity
3     tv         5
0    car         1
4  phone         6
```

Comment: `reindex` will fail if his real data has duplicates `items`  ?

Comment: @AndyL. yelp it will, However, he can  he can check other methods I provided :-)

Comment: cool! just asking to make sure I don't misunderstand `reindex`   :)

Answer (score 5):

`merge` to the rescue:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'items':['tv','car','phone']})
   .merge(df, on='items')
)
```

Output:

```
   items  quantity
0     tv         5
1    car         1
2  phone         6
```

Comment: df is not in order of the array.

Comment: @YaakovBressler Yes, and merge with the dataframe constructed from the array takes care of that.

Comment: I don't assume the array's order will be important, but what if it were? Would there be a way of maintaining that in a merge?

Comment: I don't understandt. It IS the purpose of using merge here. That is `merge` preserve the order of the GIVEN array.

Comment: The order of the array _(not that of the df)_

Comment: Yes, THE ORDER OF THE ARRAY is maintained by `merge`. Did  you even try?

Comment: I see. _My mistake, sorry._ However, the original index was lost.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another variety that uses `.loc`.

```
# Move items to the index, select, then reset.
df.set_index("items").loc[arr].reset_index()
```

Or another that doesn't change the index.

```
df.loc[df.reset_index().set_index("items").loc[arr]["index"]]
```

Comment: Note that `.loc` does not preserve the order in multiindexed Series/DataFrames. This discrepancy with `.loc` between single and multiindexed dataframes is considered a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22797) and the [solution](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/28933) is part of the milestones of Pandas 1.1.0.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a dictionary from `arr` and `map` it to `items` and `dropna`, `sort_values`

```
d = dict(zip(arr, range(len(arr))))

Out[684]: {'car': 1, 'phone': 2, 'tv': 0}

df.loc[df['items'].map(d).dropna().sort_values().index]

Out[693]:
   items  quantity
3     tv         5
0    car         1
4  phone         6
```

Answer (score 4):

For all items to be chosen existing in input `df`, here's one with `searchsorted` and should be good on performance -

```
In [43]: sidx = df['items'].argsort()

In [44]: df.iloc[sidx[df['items'].searchsorted(['tv','car','phone'],sorter=sidx)]]
Out[44]: 
   items  quantity
3     tv         5
0    car         1
4  phone         6
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
>>> df.iloc[df.loc[df['items'].isin(arr), 'items'].apply(arr.index).sort_values().index]
   items  quantity
3     tv         5
0    car         1
4  phone         6
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why not search for index, filter and re-order:**

```
df['new_order'] = df['items'].apply(lambda x: arr.index(x) if x in arr else -1)

df_new = df[df['new_order']>=0].sort_values('new_order')


   items  quantity  new_order
3     tv         5          0
0    car         1          1
4  phone         6          2
```